# Stop libinput from swiping two finger on touchpad to switch between workspaces

Tags: touchpad, workspaces, libinput, gestures

I found that once installed libinput-tool then ubuntu started to use two finger swipe(left and right) to switch between workspace! This is kind of annoying and I can't scroll horizontally in many apps. Is there any way to disable this? I have tried libinput-gestures and fusuma. But none of them worked since ubuntu recognize this action as switching between workspace first. Somebody please help.

Answer (score 0):

Fusuma doesn't recognize 2 finger swipe. Please retry with only fusuma without libinput-gestures.